# How to execute JavaScript code from a string?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

My AJAX call returns a JavaScript code which is stored in the variable `response`.

```
response = if(typeof UberUpload.startUpload == 'function'){ UberUpload.startUpload("7200c3882ecf4b509eda383b2032ec8b",0,0); }
```

I want to execute that code in response. How can I execute that JavaScript code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the JavaScript function `eval()`. So in your case `eval(response);`.

Answer (score 1):

first see the **dataType** of response, is it in `xml` or in `json` or in other format?
try `console.log(response)` first